# TikZ: Mathematical calculations in node

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'm using

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        %axis
    \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (10,0);
        \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (0,10);

   \foreach \y in {0,1,...,10}
            \draw (1pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y) 
                node[anchor=east] {\y}; 


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

to get ticks along y-axis. I want to get ticks label after multiplying be 10 something like this

```
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,10}
            \draw (1pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y) 
                node[anchor=east] {\y*10};
```

I wonder how I can get this. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs: Please my edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\pgfmathsetmacro` (or `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` if you desire only integer values):

[image]

### Notes:

- The `y=0.5cm` option was used to obtain an output that takes up less space here. You do not need to use it in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.5cm]
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,10}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Result}{\y*10}%
        \draw (1pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y) 
            node[anchor=east] {\Result};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter for your answer. Would you mind to guide me to get only whole numbers not decimal numbers? Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208: use `pgfmathtruncatemacro` rather than `pgfmathsetmacro`.

Comment: `\foreach \y [evaluate={\l=int(\y*10);}] in {0,...,10}\draw (1pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y) node [anchor=east] {\l};` would also work.