# Calculations in TikZ for iterative procedure

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

In many `\foreach` iterative procedures in TikZ I would like to relate the generic node called `n\x` -- where `x` is a natural number -- to another node the name of which is obtained by applying basic mathemathical relationships to the number used in the name of the former.

Just to be clear, I wolud like to let's say draw a line from `n\x` to `n\x+1` or to `n\x*2` or to `n\x-3`, etc. So if `x=4` I would like to draw lines like:

```
(n4)--(n5)
(n4)--(n8)
(n4)--(n1)
```

Is this possible?

In the following MWE I would like to draw lines between the nodes using an iterative procedure as previously mentioned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc} <-- Would it be necessary?

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[column sep=1cm]{
  \node (n1) {1}; & \node (n2) {2}; & \node (n3) {3}; & \node (n4) {4};\\
  };
  %\foreach \x in {1,...,3} <-- Something like this
  %\draw (n\x)--(n\x+1); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158990/tikz-mathematical-calculations-in-node) might be related, especially the comment at the end by @Mark Wibrow, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you just need to compute `\x+1` first. One way to do that is to use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I added arrows to make it clear that there were three iterations.
- As Paul Gaborit pointed out using `\pgfmathsetmacro` instead of `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` produces a real number so you get you get 3.0 instead of 3. So the arrow goes to `n3.0` (anchor with angle `0` of node `n3`).

  [image]

---

You can also use the `evaluate={\TempVar=int(\x+1)` syntax:

### Code: `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[column sep=1cm]{
  \node (n1) {1}; & \node (n2) {2}; & \node (n3) {3}; & \node (n4) {4};\\
  };
  \foreach \x in {1,...,3} {%<-- Something like this
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\TempVar}{\x+1}
      \draw [red, -latex] (n\x)--(n\TempVar); 
  }%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Code: `evaluate`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[column sep=1cm]{
  \node (n1) {1}; & \node (n2) {2}; & \node (n3) {3}; & \node (n4) {4};\\
  };
  \foreach [evaluate={\TempVar=int(\x+1);}] \x in {1,...,3} {%<-- Something like this
      \draw [red, -latex] (n\x)--(n\TempVar); 
  }%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: +1 could you avoid `\TempVar` by using `\pgfmathresult`? Is there also an `evaluate` option of some kind?

Comment: ah, I see that @TorbjørnT. got the `evaluate` thing :)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Yep, was just in the process of adding that solution. But, not sure why the results are not the same.

Comment: @PeterGrill `pgfmathtruncatemacro` :)

Comment: @PeterGrill: thanks, just what I was looking for (while you were posting your answer I was adding a link in my post to another answer of yours `:)`). I have a question: where can I find documentation about the use and math operations of `evaluate`?

Comment: @percusse: Thanks. Was in a hurry as I had to leave so was stumped as to why there was a difference.  Would like to think if I was not in such a hurry that I would have figured that out. :-)

Comment: @PierPaolo: It should be in the TikZ/pgf documentation: [TikZ manual newest version online?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49698/tikz-manual-newest-version-online).

Comment: @PeterGrill Section 56 of the TikZ/PGF deals with the syntax of `\foreach` and the `evaluate` option is discussed there, if I remember correctly `:)` I'm too lazy to check, tonight.

Comment: @PeterGrill With `\pgfmathsetmacro` (without `int(...)`), you get `3.0` instead of `3`. So the arrow goes to `n3.0` (anchor with angle `0` of node `n3`).

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Ah yes, that explains it. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @PeterGrill Hello, do you know where the documentation is for this particular form of `evaluate = {`...} that you used without loading the `math` library *(where it seems to me it's defined)*?

Comment: @AndréC: I don't know exactly but should be in the `tikz`/`pgf` document. This example loads `tikz` which loads all the math libraries it needs.

Comment: @PeterGrill TikZ does not load the `math` library by default, you have to ask it, here is the problem because `evaluate={...}` syntax is only documented in this library. That's why I'm asking myself this question.

Comment: @AndréC: Hmm, that might make a good question.

Comment: @PeterGrill That's it : [TikZ: Where is documented the syntax `evaluate={…}` used in foreach loops?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557383/138900)

Answer (score 4):

I think you just need expandable computations. Many things can be done with `\numexpr`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[column sep=1cm]{%
    \node (n11) {1}; & \node (n12) {2}; & \node (n13) {3}; & \node (n14) {4};\\
    \node (n21) {1}; & \node (n22) {2}; & \node (n23) {3}; & \node (n24) {4};\\
    \node (n31) {1}; & \node (n32) {2}; & \node (n33) {3}; & \node (n34) {4};\\
    };
  \foreach \x in {1,...,3} {%<-- Something like this
      \draw [red, -latex]
      (n\x\x)--(n\x\the\numexpr\x+1\relax);  
  }%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: nodes]

Answer (score 2):

Another version of `evaluate`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[column sep=1cm]{
  \node (n1) {1}; & \node (n2) {2}; & \node (n3) {3}; & \node (n4) {4};\\
  };
  \foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 1)] in {2,...,4}{
    \draw [red, -latex] (n\lastx)--(n\x);
  }%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to avoid the matrix

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n1) {1};
   \foreach \x in {2,...,4} {%
     \node (n\x) at (\x-1,0) {\x};
     \draw[red, -latex] (n\the\numexpr\x-1) -- (n\x);    
   }
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As nobody mentioned the use of `let`, I add this answer for the seek for completeness.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[column sep=1cm]{
  \node (n1) {1}; & \node (n2) {2}; & \node (n3) {3}; & \node (n4) {4};\\
  };
  \foreach \a in {1,...,3} {%<-- Something like this (but don't use \x inside let!)
      \draw[red, -latex] let \n{a}={int(\a+1)} in (n\a)--(n\n{a});
  }%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]