# TikZ: Where is documented the syntax `evaluate={...}` used in foreach loops?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This syntax `evaluate={...}` is documented on page 704/1318 of the `math` library . I'm quoting from the manual:

> `/tikz/evaluate=<statements>` (no default) This key simply executes
> `\tikzmath{<statements>}`.
>
> [image: example page]
>
> The following sections describe the miniature language that this
> library provides and can be used in the `\tikzmath` command and the
> `evaluate` key. The language consists only of simple keywords and
> expressions but the mini-parser allows you to format code in a
> reasonably versatile way (much like the **tikz** parser) except that
> *all the keywords must be followed by at least one space*. This is the second most important thing to remember (after remembering to insert
> semi-colons at the end of every statement).

And yet it works within a `foreach` loop **without the need to load** the `math` library.

Many answers here use the syntax `evaluate={...}` within a foreach loop instead of using the syntax documented on page 1003/1318 of the manual, which is I recall:

```
/pgf/foreach/evaluate=<variable> as <macro> using <formula>
```

For example here, [Peter Grill uses it here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160305/138900).

The manual shows its use on page 1045/1318 to illustrate the macro

```
\pgfmathtodigitlist{<macro>}{<number>}
```

with this code:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{8}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm]
\foreach \n [count=\y] in {0, 60, 102, 102, 126, 102, 102, 102, 0}{
\pgfmathdectobase{\binary}{\n}{2}
\pgfmathtodigitlist{\digitlist}{\binary}
\foreach \digit [count=\x, evaluate={\c=\digit*50+15;}] in \digitlist
\fill [fill=black!\c] (\x, -\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that produces this result

[image: page 1045]

- Why does this syntax `evaluate={...}`, which is defined *(unless I am mistaken)* in the `math` library, work **without this library** being loaded in a `foreach` loop?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: strange you've not got any answer... Have you tried https://topanswers.xyz/tex ? Marmot will know.

Comment: No, it is not strange, to answer this question, it is necessary to dive into the TikZ source code. And for that, you need time.

Comment: These two `evaluate` are different things. In `tikzlibrarymath.code.tex`, there is `\tikzset{evaluate/.code={\tikz@math{#1}}}`. And in `pgffor.code.tex`, there is `evaluate/.code=\pgffor@assign@evaluatetrue\pgffor@assign@oncefalse\pgffor@assign@parse{#1}`, so statements of two `evaluate` are actually processed in different ways. But as you say, to explain clearly need dive deeper into the source code.

Answer (score 4):

`/pgf/foreach/evaluate` is coded in `pgffor.code.tex` and is irrelavant with tikz library `math`.

From the code

```
evaluate/.code=\pgffor@assign@evaluatetrue\pgffor@assign@oncefalse\pgffor@assign@parse{#1}
```

you can see statements of `evaluate` are processed by `\pgffor@assign@parse`

```
\def\pgffor@assign@parse#1{%
    \pgfutil@in@;{#1}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \else%
        \pgfutil@in@={#1}%
    \fi%
    \ifpgfutil@in@%
        \pgffor@assign@@parse#1;\pgffor@stop;%
    \else%
        \pgffor@assign@parse@old#1\pgffor@stop%%
    \fi%
}
```

If there is a `;` in the argument, the parser is `\pgffor@assign@@parse`, otherwise `\pgffor@assign@parse@old` which corresponds to the syntax `/pgf/foreach/evaluate=<variable> as <macro> using <formula>`.

In `\pgffor@assign@@parse`, `\pgffor@assign@@@parse` with different arguments is invoked according to whether there is a `=` in the statement.

```
\def\pgffor@assign@@parse#1;{%
    \def\pgffor@test{#1}%
    \ifx\pgffor@test\pgffor@stop%
        \let\pgffor@next=\relax%
    \else%
        \let\pgffor@next=\pgffor@assign@@parse%
        \ifx\pgffor@test\pgfutil@empty%
        \else%
            \pgfutil@in@={#1}%
            \ifpgfutil@in@%
                \pgffor@assign@@@parse#1\pgffor@stop%
            \else%
                \pgffor@assign@@@parse#1=#1\pgffor@stop%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \pgffor@next}


\def\pgffor@assign@@@parse#1=#2\pgffor@stop{%
    \ifpgffor@assign@evaluate%
        \ifpgffor@assign@once%
            \pgfutil@append@tomacro{\pgffor@assign@once@code}{\pgfmathparse{#2}\let#1=\pgfmathresult}%
            \pgfutil@append@tomacro{\pgffor@remember@once@code}{\noexpand\def\noexpand#1{#2}}%
        \else
            \pgfutil@append@tomacro{\pgffor@assign@before@code}{\pgfmathparse{#2}\let#1=\pgfmathresult}%
        \fi%
    \else%
        \ifpgffor@assign@once%
            \pgfutil@append@tomacro{\pgffor@assign@once@code}{\def#1{#2}}%
            \pgfutil@append@tomacro{\pgffor@remember@once@code}{\noexpand\def\noexpand#1{#2}}%
        \else
            \pgfutil@append@tomacro{\pgffor@assign@before@code}{\def#1{#2}}%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}
```

Comment: +1 Very nice ! From this source code, is it possible for you to document the syntax of this `evaluate{}`? Are there any differences with that of the math library?